# Differences between declaring a list & appending and list()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

This below appends the `s` to the list `l`

```
 s = pd.Series([1], name='foo')
 l = []
 l.append(s)
```

This only appends `1` to `l`

```
s = pd.Series([1], name='foo')
l = list(s)
```

How to implement the first script the best way without declaring a list and then appending?

Comment: you mean `series.tolist()` ?

Comment: @anky_91 has it.  Use `l = s.tolist()`

Comment: I mean avoiding the message "The list creation could be rewritten as a list literal" from compilers.

Comment: I want a list of series.

Comment: You could use this: `l = [s]`

Comment: Do you want [s]? or l.append([s])?

Comment: Compare `['abc']` with `list('abc')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[x]` makes a list with `x` as an element.

`list(x)` makes a list produced by iterating over `x`.  `x` has to be iterable, otherwise you'll get an error.

It is, in effect, `[i for i in x]`, or

```
alist = []
for i in x:
   alist.append(i)
```